# polymer - paper drawer panel not displaying content

Tags: polymer, upgrade

I'm new to Polymer and Bower eco system, so please forgive me :). I have app written in polymer 1 and I want to upgrade single element to polymer 2. So some kind of hybrid. I've updated every dependency mentioned in upgrade guide to support polymer 2 - except for some elements with 2.0-preview, because bower was yelling that it doesn't exist.

I have following structure in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYTPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dom-bind>
            <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
                <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow="true" drawer-width="320px">
                    some content here
                </paper-drawer-panel>
            </template>
        </dom-bind>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason my page is completely blank. However, when I inspect the page, it correctly shows that there is a text "some content here". Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add import for `paper-drawer-panel` and also your `paper-drawer-panel` must have few tags inside it.

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
    <div drawer> Drawer panel... </div>
    <div main> Main panel... </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

[Paper-drawer-panel page](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel)